# Grafana Datasource Prometheus 404

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, amazon-eks

We are using AWS EKS, i deployed Promethus using the below command:

```
kubectl create namespace prometheus

helm install prometheus prometheus-community/prometheus \
    --namespace prometheus \
    --set alertmanager.persistentVolume.storageClass="gp2" \
    --set server.persistentVolume.storageClass="gp2"
```

Once this is done i get this message:
The Prometheus server can be accessed via port 80 on the following DNS name from within your cluster:

The services on my prometheus deployment looks like blow:

```
NAME                                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/prometheus-alertmanager         ClusterIP   10.22.210.131   <none>        80/TCP     20h
service/prometheus-kube-state-metrics   ClusterIP   10.12.43.248    <none>        8080/TCP   20h
service/prometheus-node-exporter        ClusterIP   None             <none>        9100/TCP   20h
service/prometheus-pushgateway          ClusterIP   10.130.54.42     <none>        9091/TCP   20h
service/prometheus-server               ClusterIP   10.90.94.70      <none>        80/TCP     20h
```

I am now using this URL in the datasource on Grafana as:

```
datasources:
  datasources.yaml:
    apiVersion: 1
    datasources:
    - name: Prometheus
      type: prometheus
      url: http://prometheus-alertmanager.prometheus.svc.cluster.local
      access: proxy
      isDefault: true
```

Grafana is also up, but when the default datasource which is prometheus in this case is unable to pull any data, when i check in the datasources tab on Grafana and try to test the datasource i am getting Error reading Prometheus: client_error: client error: 404

since both these deployments are on the same cluster ideally it should have been able to access this.
Any help here would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're targeting the wrong service. You're using the alert manager url instead of the prometheus server.
The URL should be this one :

```yaml
url: http://prometheus-server.prometheus.svc.cluster.local
```